# Is there a "reverse statement" feature in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.5

Is there a feature or plugin which can change these statements

```java
x = y;
jTextField1.setText(entity.getValue());
...
```

into these:

```java
y = x;
entity.setValue(jTextField1.getText());
...
```

Comment: If it did exist, I'd expect it to reverse the order too - x = y; z = x -> x = z; y = x ( implies y = value of z at entry ) rather than y = x; x = z; ( implies y is value of x at entry)

Comment: Yes, that would be great, but at least that could be done with any better text editor.